# How can I apply filters in elasticsearch NEST functionscore function

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

To control the score of documents based on a field value, I am using filter with function_score in my DSL query and this gets the results ordered as I expect.

However on implementing this in NEST, the results are different; the score is not applied to the filter value. From further investigation I find that some versions of C# NEST Filter is not supported with ScoreFunctionsDescriptor. Is this still the case?
Can you please assist with a working option to implement this with NEST? (I am new to Elastic Search and C# so please excuse if its a noob question).

I am currently using Elasticsearch v7.6, and NEST v7.5.1.

Thanks!

DSL query

````
GET /help/_search
{
  "query":{
   "function_score": {
     "query": {
     "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "AGC",
            "fields": [
              "title^2",
              "description^1"
            ],
            "type":"most_fields",
            "fuzziness": "AUTO:4,8",
            "prefix_length": 2,
            "boost": 5            
          }
        }
        ]
  }
  },
**  "functions": [
   { 
    "filter": {
     "term":{
       "product":"A"
            }
              },
        "weight": 45
    },
   { 
    "filter": {
     "term":{
       "product":"B"
            }
              },
        "weight": 20
    },
   { 
    "filter": {
     "term":{
       "product":"C"
            }
              },
        "weight": 10
    }
       ],**
    "score_mode": "max",
    "boost_mode": "multiply"    
}
}
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

> From further investigation I find that some versions of C# NEST Filter is not supported with ScoreFunctionsDescriptor. Is this still the case?

[The function you're looking for is a weight function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-weight) with a filter applied. This has been supported for a *long* time in the client.

The client equivalent would be something like

```cs
var response = client.Search<object>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .FunctionScore(fs => fs
            .Query(fsq => fsq
                .Bool(b => b
                    .Must(mu => mu
                        .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                            .Query("AGC")
                            .Fields(new[] { "title^2", "description^1" })
                            .Type(TextQueryType.MostFields)
                            .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.AutoLength(4,8))
                            .PrefixLength(2)
                            .Boost(5)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            .Functions(fu => fu
                .Weight(w => w
                    .Filter(f => f
                        .Term("product", "A")
                    )
                    .Weight(45)
                )
                .Weight(w => w
                    .Filter(f => f
                        .Term("product", "B")
                    )
                    .Weight(20)
                )
                .Weight(w => w
                    .Filter(f => f
                        .Term("product", "C")
                    )
                    .Weight(10)
                )
            )
            .ScoreMode(FunctionScoreMode.Max)
            .BoostMode(FunctionBoostMode.Multiply)
        )
    )
);
```

There's a couple of things that you may want to look at:

1. `description^1` can be replaced with simply `description` as the default boost is 1
2. This may be better expressed as a `bool` query with `should` clauses for each of the queries in each weight function, with a boost applied similar to how weight is being used. Something like

```cs
var response = client.Search<object>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(mu => mu
                .MultiMatch(mm => mm
                    .Query("AGC")
                    .Fields(new[] { "title^2", "description^1" })
                    .Type(TextQueryType.MostFields)
                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.AutoLength(4, 8))
                    .PrefixLength(2)
                    .Boost(5)
                )
            )
            .Should(
                sh => sh.Term(t => t
                    .Field("product")
                    .Value("A")
                    .Boost(45)
                ),
                sh => sh.Term(t => t
                    .Field("product")
                    .Value("B")
                    .Boost(20)
                ),
                sh => sh.Term(t => t
                    .Field("product")
                    .Value("C")
                    .Boost(10)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much - that worked! I have taken onboard your suggestions too.